How to create a varlist of strings and change them to numeric variables with decimals?
I have a dataset, and about half of the columns contain string responses of "Yes" "No" and "Maybe". I have the variable names of all of the columns, so a loop response would be ideal. Some of the columns don't have any "Maybe" responses, just "Yes" and "No".
I am trying to transform all of the "Yes" responses to the number 1, all of the "Maybe" responses to the number 0.5, and all of the "No" responses to the number 0.
I tried the following first (I have a long list of columns, so I tried to make a varlist of all the strings):
vl create yesnomaybe = (variable1 variable2)

foreach var of varlist yesnomaybe {
    replace `var' = strtrim(strproper(`var'))
    replace `var' = ".m" if !inlist(`var', "No", "Yes", "Maybe")  
    replace `var' = "0" if `var' == "No"
    replace `var' = "0.5" if `var' == "Maybe"
    replace `var' = "1" if `var' == "Yes"
}
destring yesnomaybe, replace 


However, I get an error after the first line. It tells me I can't make a varlist out of strings!
I also tried to use label define and encode, but label define only works with integers! (cannot assign 0.5 to "Maybe").
How would you approach this problem?

vl create is not a command I've ever used. I doubt if would really help here. It's certainly not needed if I understand your problem correctly.
I wouldn't stomp over the original data.
This is a sketch of simpler code that could be extended to several variables. Just put more variable names in the varlist. By all means change the suffix 2 according to taste and circumstance.
gen work = "" 

foreach var of varlist yesnomaybe {
    replace `work' = strtrim(strproper(`var'))
    gen `var'2 = .m if !inlist(`work', "No", "Yes", "Maybe")  
    replace `var'2 = 0 if `work' == "No"
    replace `var'2 = 0.5 if `work' == "Maybe"
    replace `var'2 = 1 if `work' == "Yes"
}

